# MySQL query to show data separated by comma with group by different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-concat

I have a MySQL table where I have stored all of users searches. So the table looks something like this

```
CREATE TABLE `users_search_activity` (
  `ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `search_keywords` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users_search_activity`
--

INSERT INTO `users_search_activity` (`ID`, `user_id`, `country_id`, `search_keywords`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 132, 2, 'xavie', '2021-07-13 08:20:37'),
(2, 132, 6, 'xavier', '2021-07-13 08:21:38'),
(3, 132, 5, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 08:21:39'),
(4, 132, 4, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 08:21:39'),
(5, 131, 9, 'xavier ins',  '2021-07-13 08:22:12'),
(6, 132, 7, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 08:22:25'),
(7, 132, 8, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:43'),
(8, 132, 6, 'xavier ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:45'),
(9, 132, 4, 'xavier insa', '2021-07-13 09:24:47'),
(10, 131, 5, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:54'),
(11, 132, 3, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:54'),
(12, 132, 2, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:58'),
(13, 132, 9, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:24:59'),
(14, 132, 0, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:25:00'),
(15, 132, 0, 'ins', '2021-07-13 09:25:02'),
(16, 132, 0, 'inst', '2021-07-13 09:58:20'),
(17, 132, 0, 'inst', '2021-07-04 09:58:25'),
(18, 132, 0, 'inst', '2021-07-07 09:58:25'),
(19, 132, 0, 'inst', '2021-07-11 09:58:26'),
(20, 1, 12, 'University Business Academy in Novi Sad', '2021-07-14 10:16:33');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `users_search_activity`
--
ALTER TABLE `users_search_activity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users_search_activity`
--
ALTER TABLE `users_search_activity`
  MODIFY `ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=20;
COMMIT;
```

Now I want to make some query from where I can get the data group by country_id and date.
So for that I have made my query like this

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_id, DATE(date) ORDER BY ID) rn, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id, DATE(date)) cnt FROM users_search_activity ) SELECT ID, cnt AS count, search_keywords, user_id, country_id, DATE(date) as date FROM cte WHERE rn = 1;
```

Here its working fine except the search_keywords. It is only showing single search_keywords. I want to show them all one by one separated by comma for the given date and country_id.

So can someone tell me how to do that? Any help or suggestions would be really appreciable.
Thanks,

The output should be something like this

```
count  user_id  country_id  date         search_keywords
 1     132       4          2021-07-13  xavier ins, xavier insa
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Something like this



`count  user_id  country_id  date         search_keywords
1    132       4          2021-07-13  xavier ins, xavier insa`

Comment: have you looked at GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: @Sam020 by using GROUP_CONCAT it is getting all the search_keywords in a single row. But I want them to show based on the country_id and date.

Comment: *... based on the country_id and date* but you also have user_id in the results.

Comment: This kind of thing is often best resolved in application code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use group_concat

```sql
WITH cte AS ( 
SELECT *,DATE(date),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY country_id, DATE(date) ORDER BY ID) rn, 
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id, DATE(date)) cnt 
  FROM users_search_activity 
  ) 
,tab2 as (
select t1.country_id,
       date(date) dat,
       group_concat(t1.search_keywords)
  from cte t1
 group by t1.country_id,
       date(date)
)
 SELECT *
  FROM cte t1,
       tab2 t2
 WHERE t1.rn = 1
   and t1.country_id = t2.country_id
   and DATE(t1.date) = t2.dat
 ;
```

update at 2021/8/3

5.7 also has `group_concat`,you just need to deal with `row_number`.

```sql
select t1.country_id,
       date(date) dat,
       group_concat(t1.search_keywords),
       max(case when t1.row_number = 1 then t1.user_id else null end) user_id
  from (
select t1.*,
       @rn := case when @temp1 is null then 1
                   when @temp1 = t1.country_id and @temp2 = DATE(date) then 0
                   else 1
              end row_number,
       @temp1:= t1.country_id,
       @temp2:= DATE(date)
  from users_search_activity t1,(select @rn:=0, @temp1:='', @temp2:='') t2
 order by country_id, DATE(date), t1.id
) t1
 group by t1.country_id,
       date(date)
;
```

Comment: Any solution for lower version of MySQL?

Comment: Which version are you using？

Comment: I have 5.7 version.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for providing such detail information in text format. Your question deserves upvote for that.

You don't need any ranking function like row_number() or cte. Simple group by with group_concat() is enough.

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id, DATE(date)) AS count, 
   user_id, country_id, DATE(date) as date, group_concat(search_keywords) FROM users_search_activity
   group by user_id,country_id,DATE(date)
```

Output:
|count | user_id | country_id | date       | group_concat(search_keywords)
|----: | ------: | ---------: | :--------- | :--------------------------------------
|  1 |     132 |          0 | 2021-07-04 | inst
|  1 |     132 |          0 | 2021-07-07 | inst
|  1 |     132 |          0 | 2021-07-11 | inst
|  1 |     132 |          0 | 2021-07-13 | inst,ins,ins
|  1 |     132 |          2 | 2021-07-13 | xavie,ins
|  1 |     132 |          3 | 2021-07-13 | ins
|  1 |     132 |          4 | 2021-07-13 | xavier insa,xavier ins
|  2 |     131 |          5 | 2021-07-13 | ins
|  2 |     132 |          5 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins
|  1 |     132 |          6 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins,xavier
|  1 |     132 |          7 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins
|  1 |     132 |          8 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins
|  2 |     131 |          9 | 2021-07-13 | xavier ins
|  2 |     132 |          9 | 2021-07-13 | ins
|  1 |       1 |         12 | 2021-07-14 | University Business Academy in Novi Sad

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb861631b1dc1ddbe0ae86b8fcc0a31c)*

Comment: This is only working with MySQL 8+ . Is there any solution for lower version?